# How to achieve removing/pruning the near-zero parameters in neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pruning

I need to remove the near-zero weights of the Neural network so that the distribution of parameters is far away from the zero point.
[The distribution of weights after removing nearzero weights and weight-scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4aQG.png)

I met the problem from this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7544366

I wonder how can I achieve this in my PyTorch/TensorFlow program, such as use a customized activation layer? Or Define a loss function that punishes the near-zero weight?

Thank you if you can provide any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for L1 regularization, [read the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/L1).

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128,
                      kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L1(.1))
```

Smaller coefficients will be turned to zero.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
However, I want to achieve the exact opposite situation, all parameters are far away from zero points. I think no matter how I adjust the coefficient of the L1 norm, the larger parameters still have a larger penalty than the smaller parameters. But I want smaller parameters to have a larger penalty.

Oh, so can I adjust the L1/L2 norm coefficient to negative?